# How do I set up an account with multiple users?

Tags: twitter

Our organisation wants to set up a single Twitter account identity with multiple users from the organisation. How do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a shared account. This feature is provided by [TweetDeck](https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/) team.

To set up your team:

1. Log in to TweetDeck with the account you wish to share access to.
2. Click Accounts in the navigation bar.
3. Select the account you’d like to share access to.
4. Click Team @[username] and type the name or @username of the user
   you’d like to invite in the Add team member field.
5. Click Authorize. Once you have authorized someone, they’ll receive
   an email as well as an invitation in the Accounts panel of their
   TweetDeck.
6. The new team member will need to accept the invitation to begin
   using the shared account.

Though, you will be provided an introductory tour of the interface when you visit the website.

<sup>**cite** https://support.twitter.com/articles/20171753</sup>